# How can I remove rows from a postgres table that all have the same value in a column, if any of those rows contains a certain value in another column?

Tags: postgresql

I have a table that looks like this:

```
Teacher   | Class | Number of students
Ms. Smith | 101   | 101
Mr. Frank | 300   | 20
Mr. Frank | 401   | 0
Mr. Smith | 102   | 20
Ms. Date  | 300   | 0
Mr. First | 100   | 10
```

I want to query and get back a table that has removed any teacher (all of their rows) who has a class of zero students, so the result I'm looking for is:

```
Teacher   | Class | Number of students
Ms. Smith | 101   | 101
Mr. Smith | 102   | 20
Mr. First | 100   | 10
```

Any idea how I can do this? I am stumped.

Comment: @RacilHilan Yes. You also have to reomove all the rows of that teacher, In the example he remove all the rows from `Mr. Frank` because one of them is 0.

Comment: I wanted not just the rows with zero students removed but also the rows with that teacher even if that row had students.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can't use subqueries:

```
SELECT t1.Teacher, t1.Class, t1.number_of_students 
FROM yourTable t1
LEFT JOIN yourTable t2
  ON t1.teacher = t2.teacher
 AND t2.number_of_students = 0
WHERE t2.teacher IS NULL
```

Comment: I am getting back that "reference to teacher is ambiguous could be teacher#5, teacher#10" I'm looking into it now but it looks as if this might be leading me to the answer for not being able to use subqueries.

Comment: check now. I forget the alias on the select fields.

Answer (score 3):

Use `not exists`:

```
select *
from teachers t
where not exists (
    select 1 
    from teachers
    where number_of_students = 0 and teacher = t.teacher)

  teacher  | class | number_of_students 
-----------+-------+--------------------
 Ms. Smith |   101 |                101
 Mr. Smith |   102 |                 20
 Mr. First |   100 |                 10
(3 rows)
```

Comment: I wondering if db engine work this query the same as `WHERE teacher NOT IN (SELECT teacher FROM table WHERE number_of_students = 0 )` ? Because in this case only need materialize one query instead of doing a sub query for each row?

Comment: The subquery is evaluated once. Performance of both variants is roughly the same, though plans are different.

Comment: @JediKid Were you able to use a subquery?

Comment: Now to make it more complicated, what if I can not have subqueries in the WHERE clause, could it be done with a JOIN?

Answer (score 1):

Your table is not normalized. You have no choice but to use the teacher name. That will be an issue if there are teachers with the same name, but here is how you do it:

```
SELECT *
FROM teachers t1
WHERE t1.teacher NOT IN (SELECT t2.teacher
                    FROM teachers t2
                    WHERE t2.teacher = t1.teacher
                    AND number_of_students = 0)
```

Or a probably simpler approach:

```
SELECT *
FROM teachers t1
WHERE (SELECT COUNT(*)
       FROM teachers t2
       WHERE t2.teacher = t1.teacher
       AND number_of_students = 0) > 0
```

Or you can use Klin's slightly better performing answer.

Comment: I like previous version more.  Explain why need an ID in case multiple `Mr.Smith`

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza I kept that explanation in the answer, but removed the code because I was afraid it would be misinterpreted. The table is not normalized, and probably can be normalized by simply replacing the name column with the ID column of the parent table, but we don't know the database design an there could be no parent table, in which case normalizing the above table means splitting it to two tables.